# Creating an Android Time object from a String

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat, string-parsing

I was just wondering if there was quick way to convert a Time object represented as a String (through it's toString() method)

`20130916T210230GMT(1,258,0,0,1379365350)`

back into a Time object or some other easy object to extract individual details from such as time / day  / month / year ect.

Is there a quick and dirty method or do we have to use something like SimpleDateFormat?

**Edit**

For clairty, I am refering to the [**Android**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) time object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar or a library like Joda (I would recommend Joda).  Just an example (you need to use formatter based on your requirements)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I'm trying this now but the format isn't right... `09-16 22:49:44.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4660): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20130916T204621GMT(1,258,0,0,13793..." is malformed at "130916T204621GMT(1,258,0,0,13793..."`